# SQL query to take top elements of ordered list on Apache Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have the table below in an SQL database.

```
user rating
1 10
1 7
1 6
1 2
2 8
2 3
2 2
2 2
```

I would like to keep only the best two ratings by user to get:

```
user rating
1 10
1 7
2 8
2 3
```

What would be the SQL query to do that? I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: mysql OR postgres not both

Comment: I am actually on Hive.

Comment: This is for postgres,if it runs on hive or how can you convert it I don\`t know     `SELECT user,rating FROM
    (SELECT user,rating,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY rating DESC) as rn FROM T) as x
    WHERE rn<=2`

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
;with cte as
(select user,rating, row_number() over (partition by user order by rating desc) maxval
 from yourtable)

select user,rating
from cte
where maxval in (1,2)
```